# PHP Trying To Count Spaces Between Paragraphs

Tags: php, html, line-breaks, spaces

I have been trying to make a PHP code that counts the lines of text stored in a .txt file
in a way so as it counts the total lines and the total spaces between paragraph's then echoes out each value along with a (Total Lines-Total Spaces) value at the end of the script unfortunately I can't get it to count spaces my current code looks like this:

```
<?php

$file="text.txt";
$spaceCount = 0;
$lineCount = 0;
$plainCount = $lineCount- $spaceCount;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");

while(!feof($handle))
{
  $line = fgets($handle);
 if(ctype_print($line)) 
 {
  $lineCount++;
 }
 else
 {
  $spaceCount++;
 }
}

fclose($handle);

?>

<html>
<body>
<?php

echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> Total lines ".$lineCount."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> Total Spaces ".$spaceCount." </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> Plain Text Count ".$plainCount."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This will be reading off a file that looks something like

```
TEXT, Text; Text
Info-info info.

Text More, Text
```

so there will be no pattern in the way it is written, Is there a way of doing this properly?

Comment: What are the expected counts for the given file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the preg_match_all function to count the spaces and other matches, some as:

```
preg_match_all("/(\s)(\n)/", $string, $matches);

$spaces = count($matches[0]);
$lines = count($matches[1]);
```